# Django file upload per user

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to create a form that will upload file per user, and i need to set the default names of the files id or something.

for example, if 2 users will upload a CV with the same name 'sampleCV.pdf' i need them to be in a seperated files, by ID or something, i tried to use self.name in the upload, but it did not work, because self is still not recognized at this point..

Is there a default way to set the file upload name?

Model

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
...
candidate_cv = models.FileField(upload_to=f'uploads/',null=True)
...
```

Form:

```
class CandidateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Candidate
        fields = '__all__'
```

view:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def create_candidate(request):
    form = CandidateForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CandidateForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'dashboard/form.html', context)
```

Form HTML:

```
{% block content %}
    <center>
        <hr>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <input class='btn btn-sm btn-danger' type="submit" name="Submit">
        </form>
        <hr>
    </center>
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple way to do this! For whom it may concern:

```
def create_candidate(request):
    form = CandidateForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CandidateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print(request.FILES['candidate_video'].name) # previous name
        request.FILES['candidate_video'].name = 'new_name.pdf' # setting a new file name
        print(request.FILES['candidate_video'].name) # new name
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context = {'form': form}
```